# How to fix the problem when I get "File not found in resource path" error?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

When I run `knit` in my rmarkdown document, it seems to work at first but eventually the following error message shows up.

```
output file: paper-1_revised.knit.md

File  not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
Execution halted
```

I checked pretty much every path for pictures used in `\includegraphics`, but they seem correct to me.
Is there any way I can fix or locate where my resource path problem lies in my code?

```
---
title: "Model"
author: |
  | jj
date: '2020-04-20'
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage{biblatex}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \usepackage{filecontents}
- \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}

bibliography: 
subparagraph: true
toc: false
number_sections: true
output: pdf_document
fig_caption: yes
fig_height: 5
fig_width: 8
includes:
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
citation_package: biblatex
---
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{key words---}} #1}
```

`````markdown
`r ''````{r, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
beta1<-0.99
beta2<-0.95
varphi<-0.12
alpha<-0.2
delta<-0.01
g<-0.02
rho<-0.8
y.n<-1.778279
k.n<-17.78279
h1.n1<-5.5246
h2.n2<-1.6545
ih1.n1<-0.1934
ih2.n2<-0.0579
ik.n<-0.6224
w<-1.4226
r<-0.02
q<-0.8569
c1.n1<-0.7851
c2.n2<-1.3288
n1<-1.3461
n2<-1.0347
n.1<-log(1.3461)
n.2<-log(1.0347)
n<-n1+n2
nl<-log(n)
y<-log(y.n*n)
k<-log(k.n*n)
h1<-log(h1.n1*n1)
h2<-log(h2.n2*n2)
ih1<-log(ih1.n1*n1)
ih2<-log(ih2.n2*n2)
ik<-log(ik.n*n)
c1<-log(c1.n1*n1)
c2<-log(c2.n2*n2)
z<-1
zeta<-c(y=y, c1=c1, c2=c2, k=k, ik=ik, h1=h1, h2=h2, ih1=ih1, ih2=ih2, n.1=n.1, n.2=n.2, nl=nl,z=1)
  
Psi <- function(zt1, zt){
#NOTE: Variables are their logarithm.
res <- matrix(NA, nrow = 13, ncol = 1)
res[1, 1] <- zt[10] + zt[2] - log(w)
res[2, 1] <- -log(6.03)-zt[6]+log(varphi/exp(zt[6])+(1+g)^(1/(1-alpha))*beta1*6.0302*(1-delta)/exp(zt1[6]))    
res[3, 1] <- log(beta1)+zt[2] - zt1[2] +log(r+1-delta)
res[4, 1] <- zt[11] -zt[3]-log(w) 
res[5, 1] <- -log(2.0168)-zt[7]+log(varphi/exp(zt[7])+(1+g)^(1/(1-alpha))*beta2*2.0168*(1-delta)/exp(zt1[7]))    
res[6, 1] <- zt[1]-zt[13]-alpha*zt[4]-(1-alpha)*zt[12]
res[7, 1] <- zt[1] -log(exp(zt[2])+exp(zt[3])+exp(zt[8])+exp(zt[9])+exp(zt[5]))
res[8,1]<-(1/(1-alpha))*log(1+g)+zt1[4]-log(exp(zt[5])+(1-delta)*exp(zt[4]))
res[9,1]<-(1/(1-alpha))*log(1+g)+zt1[6]-log(exp(zt[8])+(1-delta)*exp(zt[6]))
res[10,1]<-(1/(1-alpha))*log(1+g)+zt1[7]-log(exp(zt[9])+(1-delta)*exp(zt[7]))
res[11,1]<-log(exp(zt[2])+exp(zt[8])*6.0302*exp(zt[2])/exp(zt[6])+exp(zt[5]))-log(w*exp(zt[10])+r*exp(zt[4]))
res[12,1]<-log(exp(zt[3])+exp(zt[9])*2.0168*exp(zt[3])/exp(zt[7]))-log(w)-zt[11]  
res[13,1]<-zt1[13]-rho*zt[13]
 return(res)}

Psi(zeta, zeta)
A<- matrix(NA, 13, 13)
B<- matrix(NA, 13, 13)
for(i in 1:13){
  curz <- zeta;
  curz[i] <- curz[i]+0.00001
  PsiP <- Psi(curz, zeta)
  A[, i] <- (PsiP - 0)
  PsiP <- Psi(zeta, curz)
  B[, i] <- -(PsiP - 0)}
round(A, 4)
round(B, 4)
structure <- c(alpha = alpha, beta1 = beta1, beta2=beta2, varphi = varphi, delta = delta, rho = rho, g=g)
save(A, B, zeta, structure, file="laterUse")

```
`````

Comment: add a code chunk

Comment: @manro there are many chunks and each chunk is quite huge. In fact I check each chunk one by one, but couldn't find any seemingly possible mistake. Maybe I miss one of them, but quite frustrating.

Comment: I found. look at the line```bibliography: ``` It is empty.

Comment: @manro, thanks I just rerun the code but I got `! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile paper-1_revised.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See paper-1_revised.log for more info.
Execution halted`. Any tip?

Comment: Look, you use one package twice: ```- \usepackage{caption} - \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}``` and this: ```- \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}``` i think, you can't use with ```bibliography``` in one time

Comment: @manro, I corrected but with the same error:( I think maybe i should check over the entire document, which I really want to avoid.

Comment: I think, the best advice in your case is: "make a new Rmd file and add chunk by chunk , package by package, step by step etc."